# aws load balancer gives request 5 sec once

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I have deployed node js app on ec2 with pm2.When I used load balancer the request is made to the server 5 sec once (I have checked this using pm2 logs).But when i not created any load balancer there is no issue. What is the reason for this. Anyone please help, thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: i have seen that load balancer sends req once x seconds how to know that request generated by load balancer or client request

Comment: Requests from clients that go through the load balancer will contain the header `X-forwarded-for`. Requests orginating from the load balancer will not

Answer (score 2):

AWS Load balancers send requests to your instance at a defined interval to verify the health of the instance. Successful health checks are required for the load balancer to route requests to an instance. The interval between health checks is configurable, depending on the type of AWS load balancer you are using.